# Changes to Com Interop representation of Arrays in framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, com, interop

I'm upgrading a C# web project from the 2.0 framework to the 4.0 framework and I seem to be having some problems around the COM components it references.  It seems as though something changed that I'm not aware of around the generation of the interops.

I'm getting a number of errors like the following now without changing any of the code:

```
cannot convert from 'out string[]' to 'out System.Array'
```

For the first error above this is the prototype:

```
[id(3), helpstring("method GetAllWaves")] HRESULT GetAllWaves([out] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* ppWaves,  [out,retval] ExactaStatus *Status);
```

Here is the C# code that uses it:

```
string[] arrWaves;

m_BPStatus = m_objTXPBatchPick.GetAllWaves(out arrWaves);
```

It seems as though visual studio is now generating different method prototypes based on the same COM libraries that I was using before and it's using System.Array instead of the specific types.  Is this something new in regards to a 4.0 project or is there some setting in visual studio I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: The [out] attribute in the IDL is *very* unusual, it is not compatible with scripting languages.  Arguments like that should be passed [in,out].  The new behavior you see is not unreasonable, there is no guarantee at all that the COM component will create an array that's compatible with a "vector".  A string[] requires a single dimensional array whose first index is 0.  If you can't fix the IDL then you'll have to byte the bullet.

Comment: Thanks for the information @HansPassant.  I just found it odd that upgrading the framework to 4.0 would cause that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did find away around this.  I had to make the following code changes:

```
Array arrWaves;

m_BPStatus = m_objTXPBatchPick.GetAllWaves(out arrWaves);
Session["arrWaves"] = arrWaves.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

The key above was to change it to store it as `.Cast<string>().ToArray()`